# Simplify Java Arrays and Array lists

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist

I am trying to get rid of the Arraylist for temperatures and use just an array. I would also like a simpler method of printing out the arrays then what I am doing. The code works as it is. I am looking for a simpler way of doing it.

```
    public static void main (String [] args) {
        Scanner scnr = new Scanner(System.in);
        ArrayList<Double> temperatures = new ArrayList<>();   


        String[] days = new String[7];

        days[0] = "Monday";
        days[1] = "Tuesday";
        days[2] = "Wednesday";
        days[3] = "Thursday";
        days[4] = "Friday";
        days[5] = "Saturday";
        days[6] = "Sunday";

         for (String day : days) {
             System.out.println("Enter the temperature for: " + day);
             double temp = scnr.nextDouble();
             temperatures.add(temp);
         }

         double sum = 0.0;
         for ( int i = 0; i < temperatures.size(); i++) {
             sum += temperatures.get(i);
         }

         double average = (double) sum / temperatures.size();        


         System.out.print("You entered: ");
         System.out.print(temperatures.get(0));
         System.out.println(" for " + days[0]);



         System.out.printf("The average temperature for the week is: %.2f", average);

    scnr.close();



      return;
   }
}
```

Comment: Why would you want to get rid of `ArrayList`? If you did then `temperatures.add(temp);` would be much more complex as you would have to manage the size of the array yourself. That's not making things simpler so I don't see why you would want to do that. If for some reason you still want to work with arrays then take a look at the [Arrays class](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html)

Comment: You may want to check out [Codereview](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic). This is not a good question for SO as it asks for opinions ("simpler"?). I also don't really see what benefit you think you might get from using an array? And it should be pretty simple to convert to an array - you already know how to code with the `days` array so what is your problem in converting it?

Comment: Changing from lists to arrays *usually* makes your code more complicated, not simpler.

Comment: The exercise was to use arrays. I originally did it with two array lists and I was asked to go back and do it with just arrays.

Answer (score 1):

If you are interested in java 8+ ways to do this,(which is far cuter :-D); have a crack at this. We are using stream API to do this and you can do so much more with your array with little code,

```
    String[] days = { "Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday","Friday", "Saturday", "Sunday" };
    ArrayList<Double> temperatures = new ArrayList<>();

    Arrays.stream(days).forEach(day -> {
            System.out.println("Enter the temperature for: " + day);
            double temp = scnr.nextDouble();
            temperatures.add(temp);
        });
    double average = temperatures.stream().reduce(Double::sum).get() / temperatures.size();
    System.out.printf("The average temperature for the week is: %.2f", average);
```

Answer (score 0):

You cant do something like this (Could be cleaner with hashmap):

```
HashMap<String, Double> temperatures = new HashMap<>();
String[] days = new String[] { "Monday","Tuesday","Wednesday", "Thursday","Friday","Saturday","Sunday"};

    double sum = 0.0;
    for (String day : days) {
        System.out.println("Enter the temperature for: " + day);
        double temp = scnr.nextDouble();
        sum += temp;
        temperatures.put(day, temp);
    }

double average = (double) sum / temperatures.size();
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you only need temperatures for 1 week, you can use `double[] temp = new double[7]`

For printing, for loop is the simplest if you want to add strings in between the array values but if you just want to print array values in itself, you can use `System.out.println(Arrays.toString(yourArray));` which will output like

> [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]

if yourArray = {1,2,3,4,5}

Answer (score 0):

You can declare and initialize `days` on one line, and use it to determine the length of `temperatures` array. Assuming you're using Java 8+, you can use a `DoubleStream` to get the average of the array. And you can use `printf` to simplify your final output. Like,

```
Scanner scnr = new Scanner(System.in);
String[] days = { "Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", //
        "Friday", "Saturday", "Sunday" };
double[] temperatures = new double[days.length];
for (int i = 0; i < days.length; i++) {
    System.out.println("Enter the temperature for: " + days[i]);
    temperatures[i] = scnr.nextDouble();
}
double average = DoubleStream.of(temperatures).average().getAsDouble();
for (int i = 0; i < days.length; i++) {
    System.out.printf("You entered: %.2f for %s%n", temperatures[i], days[i]);
}
System.out.printf("The average temperature for the week is: %.2f", average);
```

Answer (score 0):

## Collections – `Map`

As commented, using Collections makes things simpler rather than arrays.

A `Map` is a collection of key-value pairs. Here we want each day of the week to map to a temperature.

## `DayOfWeek`

No need to create array of day-of-week. Java provides the [`DayOfWeek`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/DayOfWeek.html) [Enum](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/enum.html).

## `Float`

A 32-bit float is enough for temperatures. No need for 64-bit double.

## Streams

A [stream in Java](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/streams/) is a way to work through a series of values, running code against each value. Here we use stream to calculate the average of each temperature we have mapped against the day-of-week.

## Example

```
Map< DayOfWeek , Float > dayTemp = new HashMap<>();

for( DayOfWeek dow : EnumSet.allOf( DayOfWeek.class ) ) {
    System.out.println("Enter temp on: " + dow.getDisplayName( TextStyle.FULL , Locale.US ) ; 
    Float temp = scanner.nextFloat();
    dayTemp.put( dow , temp ) ;
}

Float avg = dayTemp.values().stream().average() ;
```

Answer (score 0):

This is what I came up with, I appreciate all of the help.

```
        Scanner scnr = new Scanner(System.in);
        double temp[]=new double[7];
        String[] days = {"Monday","Tuesday","Wednesday","Thursday","Friday","Saturday","Sunday"};
        double sum=0;

        for (int i=0;i<days.length;i++) {
        System.out.println("Enter the temperature for: " + days[i]);
        temp[i] = scnr.nextDouble();
        sum+=temp[i];
        }

        double average = sum / temp.length;

        for(int i=0;i<days.length;i++){
        System.out.println("You entered "+temp[i]+" for "+days[i]);
        }

        System.out.printf("%nThe average temperature for the week is: %.2f", average);

        scnr.close();

        return;

        }

}
```